# How to unit test this method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I'm a newbie in c# .net so please go easy on me if the question seems trivial.

I am using dll that exposes methods through Interface IClientDetails and IScanService. Following is in my controller:

```
IClientDetails _clientdetails;
IScanService _scanservice;

HomeController(IClientDetails clientdetails, IScanService scanservice)
{
    _clientdetails =  clientdetails;
    _scanservice = scanservice;
}

public JsonResult CreateScan(ClientGroup cg, Version version)
{
    //do something and return JSON Result like this
    return Json(new {Messgae = "created", Success = true});
}
```

Note: Here on debugging I see clientdetails and scnaservice are initiated and have data. They are initiated  by some method in dll.

```
public interface IClientDetails
{
    IQueryable<ClientGroup> ClientGroup {get;}
    //other functions and members
}
```

When I write the Unit Test class (for **CreateScan** method), I can pass IclientDetails client in constructor and can see that it will be intiialized but in UnitTest class constructor, params cannot be passed. How can I use the initiated values in my unit test class.
Using it otherwise by directly passing the IClientDetails clientdetails variable to constructor of controller class from unittest method says that: `type is being used as var`.

Comment: Just look at the `MOQ` or `FakeItEasy` documentation, it's pretty straight-forward

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "in UnitTest class constructor, params cnnot be passed?"

Comment: @DanPuzey In unit test constructor, params cannot be passed as it is not allowed in Unit test framework of vs.

Comment: Alright, I think I understand. Why do you want to pass these in to the constructor of the unit test class? Typically it would be expected for your unit test class to *create* those objects.

Comment: It's not really clear what the issue is here.  What are you actually testing?  The `HomeController` constructor?  You can pass mock objects to that constructor.  But then how are you going to validate the result of the test?  What are you asserting?  Or are you testing the `CreateScan` method?  If that's the case you'd set up your mocks to behave in an expected way and validate the result of that method based on that expected behavior.  You indicate some compiler error with the unit test itself, but you don't show that code...